# route file issues in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

When i write below code in route file it work perfectly but my "admin panel" redirect on frontend page(frontend/login/process  link)(not show).

When i comment this, admin panel / frontend both working perfectly  but not show this list page.

```
$route['(:any)'] = "frontend/home/productlist/$1";
```

I have used others in route file. Is there any issue let me know please.

```
$route['process'] = "frontend/login/process";

$route['admin']="admin/login";

$route['admin/product/(:num)'] = 'admin/product/index/$1';

$route['(:any)'] = "frontend/home/productlist/$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this :

```
$route['/(:any)'] = "frontend/home/productlist/$1";
```

Comment: This answer would be better with some explanation.